# Can ASP.NET5 run on Linux without mono?

Tags: linux, asp.net, mono-framework

After reading Scott Hanselman's blog post [Announcing .NET 2015](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnnouncingNET2015NETAsOpenSourceNETOnMacAndLinuxAndVisualStudioCommunity.aspx) he says

> ASP.NET 5 will be available for Windows, Mac, and Linux. Mac and Linux
>   support will come soon...

Does this mean that the .NET framework will be officially supported on Mac and Linux without any dependance on Mono? Have I interpreted that correctly?

Comment: You have indeed interpreted it correctly.  I should clarify.  A version of .ASP .NET will work on Mac and Linux.  What won't be ported over are those features that require Windows libraries for instance `Windows Authentication`.  I don't believe Microsoft, will be doing the porting, that will be up to the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have interpreted it correctly.  ASP.NET 5 will run on a new runtime called .NET Core.  Scott Guthrie described 3 main features of .NET Core on [his blog](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5):

> 1. You can deploy the .NET Core runtime with your app which means your app will run with this deployed version of the runtime rather than the version of the runtime that is installed on the host operating system.
> 2. Your app is only dependent on features it really needs. Therefore, you are never prompted to update/service the runtime for features that are not relevant to your app.
> 3. Your app can now be run cross-platform. We will provide a cross-platform version of .NET Core for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X systems.

So, Microsoft will be providing a runtime environment for all three operating systems.  As of this writing .NET Core is not yet completed.  They have Windows support but Mac OS X and Linux support is still pretty limited.  You can follow the development of .NET Core on their [Github page](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr).

Comment: How will the performance of .NET Core on Linux compare to .NET Framework on Windows?